# Django - Adding a second database entry causes failure. Django no longer uses 'default'

Tags: django, database, postgresql, migration

My database and project work great using this database setting:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'myprojectdb',
        'USER': 'myprojectuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'my_secret_password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True
    },
}
```

But I want to add a 'readonly' database entry for my readonly db user, like this, so that I can run [django-sql-explorer](https://github.com/groveco/django-sql-explorer):

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'myprojectdb',
        'USER': 'myprojectuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'my_secret_password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True
    },
    'readonly': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'myprojectdb',
        'USER': 'myprojectreadonly',
        'PASSWORD': 'your_eyes_only_secret',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True
    }
}
```

And now django throws a couple different errors. If I try to do anything with migrations, I get:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: permission denied for relation django_migrations
```

If I try to runserver, I get:

```
"AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model '%s' that has not been installed" % settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'users.User' that has not been installed
```

It seems like when I add the second database setting, django is attempting to use that for migrations, running the server, etc, even though it's not 'default'

If I comment out the second entry, everything works great again.

Any recommendations on how to correct this?

---

Edit: If I change the settings to use the same username and password, everything works great, so it's not just an issue of django being confused on names. IE:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'myprojectdb',
        'USER': 'myprojectuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'my_secret_password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True
    },
    'readonly': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'myprojectdb',
        'USER': 'myprojectuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'my_secret_password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The two configurations shares the same database names  `'NAME': 'myprojectdb'`
So when you try to migrates dbname seems to conflicts so the applications is having an indecision on which to use The previous or the later

Comment: But unless I explicitly tell django to use a particular connection, shouldn't it default to 'default'? Or am I misunderstanding how this works? Also, NAME is the database name (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#name), so if both db users use the same database, this value must remain the same, right?

Comment: In fact, the docs say "The default routing scheme ensures that if a database isn’t specified, all queries fall back to the default database." (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/multi-db/#automatic-database-routing), but it seems to be failing to work correctly in this case.